# How to switch between different windows in the same frame without using mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

How to switch between different windows in the same frame without using mouse?

When I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and switch from some other application to Emacs, how to go to one window and subsequently switch to another window in the same frame without using mouse?

Comment: You should try the tutorial with `C-h t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-x o` for `other-window` is the most basic way to do this.  You might want, as I have, to rebind something else to that (`C-tab`), or to investigate some of the other window movement options - the `windmove` library is useful for directional movement.

Comment: `C-x o` works. How to to rebind it to `C-tab`?

Comment: http://xahlee.org/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html